# Argument of $\operatorname{cis}(2π/7) + 1$ without a calculator?

Tags: complex-numbers

The full question goes: If $\omega$ is the solution to $z^7 = 1$ with the least positive argument, determine the argument of $1 + \omega$. Express your answer in terms of $\pi$.

And the mark scheme goes: $\omega$ has argument $2\pi/7$ and $1 + \omega$ has argument $\phi$, then $$\tan\phi = \frac{\sin\frac{2\pi}7}{1+\cos\frac{2\pi}7} = \frac{2\sin\frac\pi7\cos\frac\pi7}{2\cos^2\frac\pi7} = \tan\frac\pi7$$ therefore $\phi = \frac\pi7$.

Could someone please explain how tan came into the picture and why the expression is $ \tan\phi = \frac{\sin\frac{2\pi}7}{1+\cos\frac{2\pi}7}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

All you need here is basic high-school geometry:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @TonyK (+1) What did you use to draw this?

Comment: @PeterForeman: I used a free on-line tool called [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org). It's rather basic, and a bit annoying at times, but for stuff like this it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $e^{2\pi i/7}+1 = |e^{2\pi i/7}+1|e^{i\phi}$. We have
$$\cos\phi + i\sin\phi  = \frac{\left(1+\cos\frac{2\pi}7\right) + i\sin\frac{2\pi}7}{\sqrt{\left(1+\cos\frac{2\pi}7\right)^2 + \sin^2\frac{2\pi}7}}= \frac{\left(1+\cos\frac{2\pi}7\right) + i\sin\frac{2\pi}7}{\sqrt{2\left(1+\cos\frac{2\pi}7\right)}}$$

so $\cos\phi = \frac{1+\cos\frac{2\pi}7}{\sqrt{2\left(1+\cos\frac{2\pi}7\right)}}$ and $\sin\phi = \frac{\sin\frac{2\pi}7}{\sqrt{2\left(1+\cos\frac{2\pi}7\right)}}$.

Therefore

$$\tan\phi = \frac{\sin\phi}{\cos\phi} = \frac{\sin\frac{2\pi}7}{1+\cos\frac{2\pi}7} = \frac{2\sin\frac\pi7\cos\frac\pi7}{2\cos^2\frac\pi7} = \frac{\sin\frac\pi7}{\cos\frac\pi7}=\tan\frac\pi7$$
so $\phi = \frac\pi7$ because $e^{2\pi i/7}+1$ is in the first quadrant.